# Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs?

Tags: support, search, hyperlinks, faq-proposed, architecture

I have found mentions of various Stack Exchange engine URLs (/question/NNNN, [/question/NNNN/question-title-spelled-out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155878/stack-overflow-url-format), /answer/NNNN, [/user/NNNN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22046), [/q/NNNN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164197), /a/NNNN, [/u/NNNN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244784), etc.)  scattered around in different places, including sometimes just-in-passing mentions that a link can also including a user id, [/a/NNNN/UUUU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305392) or can have suffixes such as [?lastactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313428) or [?rq=](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313471/add-canonical-urls-to-avoid-duplicate-search-engine-results?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1057237_313471).

Is there some unified location where all these sorts of URLs are documented?

(I did find https://api.stackexchange.com/docs which documents the somewhat-similar-looking API calls, but am trying to find documentation for the regular Stack Exchange engine website URLs instead.)

Comment: Nice question, I've been thinking for a while about asking something like "how many specifically coded URLS should link to a certain question/answer?"

Comment: I've added a rather long list for the 'core' Q&A functionality and user pages, since they are used most often. I realize I've skipped e.g. the Help Center, review pages, elections, and probably a dozen other topics. I'm not sure if those are really interesting and worth documenting, since they do not involve so many redirects/hidden parameters.

Comment: @Glorfindel, yes I was particularly interested in the "shortcut" URLs which redirect within the Q&A system, e.g. URLs that might be suitable for linking to  a specific topic and/or answer on some external Wiki page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/295232) but it only covers URLs you normally wouldn't find. I don't think there's a unified location document for 'public' URLs, so here's an attempt:

### Questions

- Canonical form: /questions/[question ID]/[question title]

  - Most links generated by the site itself have this form (e.g. question lists, sidebar widgets)
  - [question title] is not the full title if it's longer than 80 characters
  - What you type as [question title] doesn't matter; if you type something else, it'll still redirect to the canonical form (which exists [for SEO purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25259/4751173))
  - If you use an answer ID instead of a question ID, it'll still work and redirect to the canonical form (of the answer)
  - Parameters ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142535/295232) is an extended but not up-to-date list, these are the ones I see the most):

    - `lq=1`: visited from the Linked Questions sidebar widget
    - `rq=1`: visited from the Related Questions sidebar widget
    - `noredirect=1`: prevents redirection to original question in the following cases:

      - [Questions with no answers closed as duplicates of one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/295232) (only active for anonymous users)
      - Questions migrated to other sites (i.e. migration stubs) (always prevented for moderators)
    - `lastactivity`: links to the last activity (edited post, new answer) on the page
    - `cb=1`: visited from the Community Bulletin (sidebar widget with Meta posts and blog links)
    - `r=SearchResults`: visited from a search results page. In this case, a parameter `s=[rank]|[relevance]` is added as well; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242925/295232) for more details.
    - `answertab=[sort]`, where `[sort]` is one of `active`, `oldest`, `votes`, makes sure the right sort is set (regardless of the user's current choice). Often combined with a `#tab-top` fragment to scroll down to the answers.
- Short form: /q/[question ID] or /q/[question ID]/[user ID]

  - This is the link you get by clicking the [share link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63684/295232) underneath a question; the user ID is the one currently logged in, not the author. It makes sure the link counts for the [Announcer](/help/badges/74/announcer) badge and its kin.
  - If you use an answer ID instead of a question ID, it'll still work and redirect to the canonical form (of the answer)
  - If you use the ID of a tag wiki or excerpt, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62883, it will redirect to the tag info page.
- An obscure form, used in the newsletter: /landing/r/newsletter?cta=question&id=[question ID]

### Answers

- Canonical form: /questions/[question ID]/[question title]/[answer ID]#[answer ID]

  - This is basically an extended version of the canonical question URL; again, only the question ID and the last answer ID matter (the latter because it scrolls the page to the right position).
  - The first answer ID matters if there are too many answers to fit on a single page; [it makes sure the correct page is displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155878/stack-overflow-url-format?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment448573_155882).
- Short form: /a/[answer ID] or /a/[answer ID]/[user ID]

  - If you use a question ID instead of an answer ID, it'll still work and redirect to the canonical form (of the question)
  - The global inbox uses this format (with `noredirect=1`) when somebody posts an answer to one of your questions.

### Posts / revisions

- Edit post: /posts/[post ID]/edit
- Revision history: /posts/[post ID]/revisions

  - Can be visited via the 'edited x hours ago' link underneath a post, but works when there is only a single revision too.
  - The global inbox uses this format for notifications that one of your posts has been edited.
- Single revision (rendered): /revisions/[post ID]/[revision number]
- Edit post, starting from a particular revision: /posts/[post ID]/edit/[revision GUID]
- Single revision (markdown): /revisions/[revision GUID]/view-source
- Timeline: /posts/[post ID]/timeline

### Comments

- Canonical forms:

  - /questions/[question ID]/[question title]#comment[comment ID]_[question ID]
  - /questions/[question ID]/[question title]/[answer ID]#comment[comment ID]_[answer ID]
  - Most of the remarks about questions and answers applies here, too
- Short form: /posts/comments/[comment ID]

  - This format (with a `noredirect=1` parameter) is used in the global inbox.

### Users

- Most URLs support `current` instead of a user ID. This will automatically be populated with the user who is currently logged in, so e.g. /users/current will [redirect to your own user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187935/295232).
- Canonical form: /users/[user ID]/[display name]

  - What you type as [display name] doesn't matter; if you type something else, it'll still redirect to the canonical form (which exists for SEO purposes)
  - For your own user (for ♦ moderators, *all* users), this shows the Activity page; for other users, the Profile page
  - Navigation is possible with

    - the `tab` parameter (for the top tab: Profile / Activity and the second Activity tab (Summary / Answers / Questions etc.)
    - the `sort` parameter (for subtabs; sometimes it does affect the sorting, e.g. answers by votes or by creation date; sometimes it's just an additional filter, e.g. with votes)
    - the `page` parameter
- Short form: /u/[user ID]

  - [Even works for deleted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297554/295232) (♦ moderators are able to view them)
  - Doesn't support `current`
- Flag summary: /users/flag-summary/[user ID]

  - Normally only works on your own user ID; ♦ moderators can view other users' flag summaries as well.
- Edit profile page: /users/edit/[user ID]

  - Normally only works on your own user ID; ♦ moderators can edit other users' profiles and some of the subpages as well.
  - Edit subpages have their own URL structure, e.g. /users/email/settings/[user ID] for the email settings and /users/delete/[user ID] for the 'Delete account' page.
- Deleted posts: /users/deleted-questions/[user ID] and /users/deleted-answers/[user ID]

  - Normally only works on your own user ID; ♦ moderators can view them for other users as well.

Comment: Great, thanks, very helpful.  Just curious how you came to know about all of these?  Was it just making a mental note of URLs you noticed as you used the system over a period of time, or was there some more direct route to compiling this information?

Comment: ... let's just say I spend too much time here ...

Comment: As an example, while researching for this answer I stumbled upon the /posts/comments/ short form. I never knew it existed, until I checked a few obvious places to look for system generated URLs.

Comment: Just a check: on  /users/recently-deleted-questions a mod sees the same as the user or do they get to see all deleted questions?

Comment: They see the same as the user; they'd have to use the search functionality (`user:12345 deleted:1 is:q`) to see all deleted questions.

Comment: Don't forget the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/332251/timeline).

Comment: @Mast that link is already mentioned in the [List of unlinked pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/295232).

Comment: So is `/revisions`, yet you mentioned that in your post. That's kind-of where I expected `/timeline` too. Oh well, at least it's indirectly mentioned. Very nice feature.

Comment: But /revisions is *not* an unlinked page (unless there is only a single revision). So it belongs here but not in the other post :)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The 'problem' is indeed with the other answer, not with yours.

Comment: Interesting that a link to an answer from the search page ends with something like `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/stack-overflows-robots-txt-is-completely-useless/44082?r=SearchResults&s=1|13.2247#44082` (I searched for `blab`) The `s=1|13.2247` part is undocumented and seems to be (based on other tests) `s=<position_in_results_page|<matching_ratio>`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' interesting, that `s` parameter appears for me only *after* I've clicked the link. Might be worth a question by itself ...

Comment: Oh, the link to the answer in https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=blab does not have the `s` parameter to you? I checked with private window and normal one and it always does to me.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' nope: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OM6V.png Related discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242925/295232

Comment: For comments, there are also [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000), e.g. `[edit]`, `[mcve]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[mre]`, `[example]`, `[tag:tag-name]`, `[meta-tag:tag-name]`, `[meta]`, `[main]`, `[help]`, `[tour]`, `[so]`, `[mathoverflow.se]`, and `[chat]`. Rendered (not all work in this special place, but they work on the normal sites): [edit], [mcve], [reprex], [repro], [mre], [example], [tag:tag-name], [meta-tag:tag-name], [meta], [main], [help], [tour], [so], [mathoverflow.se], and [chat].

Comment: Are the `r` and `s` parameters only valid on questions? Context: [Answer links from search pages do not load the page at the linked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359561/284827).

Comment: What about the help center ones, [like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387354/where-can-we-find-a-site-charter-purpose-that-tells-us-the-types-of-question-on#comment1291391_387355) `/help/on-topic` and `/help/off-topic`?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum as far as I know, those are relatively simple (static, no parameters), so they don't fall under "all these sorts of URLs" as meant by the OP. Yes, there are some redirections like https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice, but I feel those are better left for another Q&A (if they're worth documenting at all).