# Which URL structure should I use when archiving questions in the Wayback Machine?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, archive

There are several URLs one could use to get to a question. For example:

- `https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124409/can-stocks-trade-at-negative-prices`
- `https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124409/`
- `https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124409`
- `https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124409/`
- `https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124409`

When I am saving a question to the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine (https://web.archive.org), which URL should I use to archive the question?

Comment: All of those links redirect to the same location on our site. So it really depends on how the Wayback Machine handles redirects. If it just records that it hit a redirect and doesn't follow, then all but the final URL would be useless. If it follows the redirect and archives the resulting page, then which one you use doesn't matter. That is a question for the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter; the Wayback Machine will always follow the redirects and end up at the ['canonical URL'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/295232), the first one: `https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124409/can-stocks-trade-at-negative-prices`. This is what happens when you archive `https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124409`:

[image]

This does mean a question's history can get fragmented in the Wayback Machine. If you search for `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-do-they-do` now you'll only get [one hit](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-do-they-do):

[image]
<sub>([blame Catija :P](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/99338/17))</sub>

It's better to go to this URL: [`https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/*`](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/*) (I don't see a form to navigate to it, but it will be suggested if you search for `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/*`); then you'll see all of its available history:

[image]

All of it? Nope; some of the older content here used to be hosted at the meta.stackoverflow.com domain. So in this case there's [`https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99338/*`](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99338/*) as well:

[image]

with another three hits. Note that some main sites (e.g. [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://programmers.stackexchange.com)) have been renamed in the past as well.