# Short links to comments on election nominations lead to server error

Tags: bug, comments, election, 500-server-error

First off, this is probably the least significant bug I've ever reported.  I'm not sure it's actually worth fixing.  But it *is* a bug, so for completeness's sake... (and hey, maybe someone at SE is wondering where that error in the logs came from).

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122929746 is the [short form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/165261) of a link to a comment on an election nomination ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=nomination#comment122929746_69547373), specifically).

But instead of opening the election page and jumping to the comment, it leads to the "Oops!" page indicating a server error.  This is different than the behavior for a deleted comment (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2345)), which leads to the standard 404 page.

Comment: Something else I noticed that might be work looking into: if you visit the election page from the link in the bulletin (i.e., [/election?cb=1](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)), comment timestamps are _not_ clickable for some reason. But if you visit /election or /election/id, they're clickable.

Comment: Can this be reproduced in SE sites? I checked in [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination). I can't find the comment links there. So should your post be in Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RandomPerson you have to be on the Nomination tab to see the comments.

Comment: @RyanM I was in the nomination tab and I was able to see the comments in Biblical Hermeneutics. But I couldn't find the comment links in [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination).

Comment: @RandomPerson the comment link (and its ID) is on the timestamp. This short link is manually formed using the format `posts/comments/[comment_id]`.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I understood about the short link format. What I am saying is that there is no comment link on the timestamp in the comments of [Biblical Hermeneutics election nomination page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination). So I feel [Ryan's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370893) is only applicable to Stack Overflow, so it is better suited for Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Take a look at these GIFs: Meta Stack Overflow (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHO8Q.gif) and Biblical Hermeneutics (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZjcg.gif).

Comment: The error is reproducible on BH as well: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/139081

Comment: @RandomPerson ah, I see. I clicked the "Nomination" tab again and it redirected to `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination` (note the `/2`) and there's the link, exactly as 4168....'s comment (another election page bug?) stated.

Comment: @41686d6564 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370933