# Is it possible to see if a post has been linked somewhere?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, linked-questions

Is it possible to see if and toward what a post (question or answer or comment) has been linked? For example if you [click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) you get to the main meta.se page but is it possible to see that that page has been linked from here?

Just to make an example (and I'm not going to use specific names to keep it general):

On a certain SE I stumbled upon an answer which is the most voted and the chosen one. Unfortunately it is wrong. By chance I've seen that on *another SE* an answer is linked to that wrong one. So it would be interesting to see where that wrong answer has been linked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way for Stack Exchange to keep track of all links like that. The following functionality *is* available and may be of help in similar situations:

- The [linked-questions](/questions/tagged/linked-questions) functionality, which shows posts on the same site referencing each other in a list in the right sidebar; I'm not sure how familiar you are with the Stack Exchange software but the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/linked-questions/info) contains some details, and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/26/new-linked-posts/) is the blog post that introduced the feature.
- You can use the [`url:` search operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) to search for a post's URL. The operator even works on https://stackexchange.com/ for network-wide searches. It only searches in posts though, and you cannot limit your search query to just `https://meta.stackexchange.com/` (without anything after it), so it works best for links to specific posts, just as in your example. Note that there are [various ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/295232) to link to specific posts; if I'd want to look for links to this answer, I could search for

  - `https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382331` (the relevant part of the short form)
  - `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382330/` (yes, this is the *question*, but using the entire URL, `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382330/is-it-possible-to-see-if-a-post-has-been-linked-somewhere/382331#382331` may have the problem that if the title changes, that URL changes as well - older links may use a different title.
  - Searching for `url:"382331"` might also work, but could also give false positives.
- A search for specific URLs is also possible with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) provided that the site is not too large (Stack Overflow is too large for searching posts like that). [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1646737?query=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com) is an example, but you'd need to run it again for the same URL with another slash at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that should help  I'm going to expand a bit my question with an example, just to be sure that it's clear what and why I'm asking about