# Can I "backtrack" intra-SE links?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, linked-questions

Is it possible to find questions/answers/comments that link to a given question/answer/comment?

Suppose [someone were to ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/727970/does-the-earth-s-rotational-angular-velocity-change) a question about the rotation of the Earth.  [Someone else notices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/727970/does-the-earth-s-rotational-angular-velocity-change#comment1628042_727970) that this question is similar [to an older question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721256/55662) and says as much.  If the author of and visitors to the new question might reasonably be interested in the older question and its answers, it seems plausible that the author of and visitors to the older question might reasonably be interested in the newer question and its answers.  Since the newer question links to the older question, is it possible using Stack Exchange search sorcery to find the newer question given the older question?

Comment: If someone posts a link to that question, either plain or in markup, it will show up in the right hand side of the screen listed under "Related"

Comment: @Luuklag that goes the opposite direction from what OP wants if I'm understanding correctly. "*is it possible [...] to find the newer question given the older question?*"

Comment: @scohe001 Luuklag's suggestion does just that.  After Luuklag's comment I noticed a "Linked" list at the bottom of the older question that has the newer question there.

Comment: @scohe001 it works both ways around.

Comment: Regarding 'SE sorcery', you can enter the url https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/721256?lq=1 to get the list of linked questions, 721256 being the id of the older question.

Comment: [Is it possible to see if a post has been linked somewhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382330/295232) (disclaimer: I answered that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes you can!

On the right hand side of the question page, or on the bottom of the page if you are on a narrow viewport, there are the *Linked* and *Related* questions.

Every question has its own Related questions, and those suggestions are based on a search, as described by [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected).

[image: Screenshot showing this question and its Related questions. The word Related has been highlighted with a freehand red circle.]

Linked questions start to show up once someone links a question with another question. This can be done by incorporating a link to a different question into a comment, answer or the question itself. This works in both directions.

**Example:** when a link to question X is posted in a comment on question Y, the Linked questions of question X will also show question Y.

This can also be seen on your linked examples:

**New question** with link to old question posted in the comments, shows the old question in the Linked questions.
[image]

**Old question** with the link to the new question.
[image]

As a bonus, as [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382812/can-i-backtrack-intra-se-links#comment1276721_382812) in the comments by [Marijn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/704954/marijn), you can also directly access the list of Linked questions using https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/721256?lq=1 where 721256 is the ID of the old question.